# Node- Cannot GET /api/posts

Tags: node.js, reactjs, express, react-redux, react-hooks

I am making a blog app, where the users can view posts written by them and other user. But unfortunately I am unable to view the posts. Everything else is working fine, even the backend APIs were working. But I am still not able to view the posts
Thank You in advance

[image]

action/post.js

```
import api from "../utils/api";
import { setAlert } from "./alert";
import { GET_POSTS, POST_ERROR } from "./types";

//GET posts
export const getPosts = () => async (dispatch) => {
  try {
    const res = await api.get("/posts");

    dispatch({
      type: GET_POSTS,
      payload: res.data,
    });
  } catch (error) {
    dispatch({
      type: POST_ERROR,
      payload: {
        msg: error.response.statusText,
        status: error.response.status,
      },
    });
  }
};
```

Node(routes)- post.js

```
const express = require("express");
const router = express.Router();
const { check, validationResult } = require("express-validator");
const auth = require("../../middleware/auth");

const Post = require("../../models/Post");
const User = require("../../models/User");
const checkObjectId = require("../../middleware/checkObjectId");

// @route       POST api/post
// @description Create a post
// @access      Private

router.post(
  "/",
  auth,
  check("text", "Text is required").notEmpty(),
  async (req, res) => {
    const errors = validationResult(req);
    if (!errors.isEmpty()) {
      return res.status(400).json({ errors: errors.array() });
    }

    try {
      const user = await User.findById(req.user.id).select("-password");

      const newPost = new Post({
        text: req.body.text,
        name: user.name,
        avatar: user.avatar,
        user: req.user.id,
      });

      const post = await newPost.save();

      res.json(post);
    } catch (err) {
      console.error(err.message);
      res.status(500).send("Server Error");
    }
  }
);

// @route       GET api/posts
// @description Get all posts
// @access      Private

router.get("/", auth, async (req, res) => {
  try {
    const posts = await Post.find().sort({ date: -1 });
    res.json(posts);
  } catch (err) {
    console.error(err.message);
    res.status(500).send("Server Error");
  }
});

// @route       GET api/post/:id
// @description Get post by ID
// @access      Private

router.get("/:id", auth, checkObjectId("id"), async (req, res) => {
  try {
    const post = await Post.findById(req.params.id);

    if (!post) {
      return res.status(404).json({ msg: "No Post found" });
    }

    res.json(post);
  } catch (err) {
    console.error(err.message);

    res.status(500).send("Server Error");
  }
});


module.exports = router;
```

server.js

```
const express = require("express");
const connectDB = require("./config/db");

const app = express();

//Database
connectDB();

//Middlware
app.use(express.json({ extended: false }));

app.get("/", (req, res) => res.send("API is Running"));

//Routes
app.use("/api/users", require("./routes/api/users"));
app.use("/api/auth", require("./routes/api/auth"));
app.use("/api/profile", require("./routes/api/profile"));
app.use("/api/post", require("./routes/api/post"));

const PORT = process.env.PORT || 5000;

app.listen(PORT, () => console.log(`Server started on port ${PORT}`));
```

Comment: So is it api/post or api/posts?

Comment: If the server responds with a 404, that is where the problem lies of course, no need to post the irrelevant source code for your frontend client

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The route registered in [server.js](https://github.com/Trungks82/blog-app/blob/master/server.js#L15) is `/api/post`, so in your [actions/post](https://github.com/Trungks82/blog-app/blob/master/client/src/actions/post.js#L8) it should be `/post`. This should fix your problem.